# Syntax Error with open(logPath, 'r') as fh:

Tags: python, deque, python-2.5

```
with open(logPath, 'r') as fh:
    for line in TailDeque(fh, 20):
        gamethread.delayed(0, show_recentlyCommands, (userid, text))
```

I always get an Error in the line `with open(logPath, 'r') as fh:`

I'm using Python 2.5 and using the TailDeque.

Comment: Fix the indent ... Error will auto-disappear

Comment: Please show the complete error message.  The way you pasted the code, it looks like you have an indentation error (the stuff under the `with` should be indented another level).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2.5 supports the `with` statement only optionally; you need to have this as the **first** line in *each* file that uses the `with` statement:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

The `with` statement works without `__future__` import since Python **2.6**